# Получить новый список который содержит сумму всех чисел стоящих справа от данного числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать получение нового списка в котором будут вместо исходных цифр, сумма все цифр стоящих правее от данного числа

Comment: зачеи для хранения суммы целый список??

Comment: для каждого числа находящегося в изначальном списке должна сумма чисел стоящих справа от данного

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно по круче)

```
[sum(x[i:]) for i in x]
```

где х - ваш список

`для произведения` все так красиво не оформишь, можно циклом, но если время исполнения не важно, то так:

```py
import numpy
[numpy.prod(numpy.array(x[i:])) for i in x]
```

Comment: Вот это элеганто!

Comment: способ классный, но как поступить если необходимо найти произведение?

Comment: А теперь представьте, что у вас миллион элементов. Вы каждый раз делаете слайс, то есть производите копирование, что уже не очень хорошо сказывается на используемой памяти. А потом суммируете элементы, не принимая во внимание, что сумма уже посчитана для правых соседей. Элегантность - это конечно здорово и возможно для этой задачи производительность не важна, но все-таки нужно осознавать время работы алгоритмов.

Comment: @KirillKorolev кто смеет говорить про оптимизацию, при этом имея код на питоне?)) а вообще вы ясное дело правы, но я не заметил никаких условий задачи, аля длинна списка 10 ^20 и подобное, так что тут такая сложность вполне уместна

Comment: @yavis добавил для произведения

Answer (score 5):

С использованием дополнительной памяти

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = len(xs)
sums = [0] * n

for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    sums[i - 1] = sums[i] + xs[i]

print(sums)
```

И на месте

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = len(xs)

last = xs[n - 1]
xs[n - 1] = 0

for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    tmp = xs[i - 1]
    xs[i - 1] = xs[i] + last
    last = tmp

print(xs)
```

Comment: список же можно создавать динамически)